# QGIS connection to MSSQL Server issue - no geometry columns table found

Tags: qgis

I know that this question has been asked before but I believe my case is a little different... We do have a geometry columns table as well as a spatial references table in our spatial database, however I still have following error message.

[image]

Like I said, we have a geometry table and a spatial references table for QGIS to look at.
[image]

When I add a new connection, ONLY these newly created feature classes in our database are recognised as spatial data. All the old entries are recognised as non-spatial tables.
[image]

Following is the details of above two tables in geometry columns table

[image]

I am puzzled. Anyone could shed some light please?

Comment: Your tables are not native MSSQL spatial tables but they are made with ESRI SDE tools. For reading those with QGIS you should have a GDAL version that has been built with the SDE driver http://www.gdal.org/drv_sde.html.

Comment: Cheers mate, I have read your link over the weekend, just wondering if you can make it more clear for me please? Does this driver need to be installed on my computer or on the machine that installed ArcSDE ? Do you have a procedure to follow? Many thanks again!!

Comment: You should have the SDE driver on your computer. For installing it you need some libraries from ESRI and I have been reading that it may be tricky to compile the driver.

Comment: Thanks for your help...though I am still puzzled....I searched this forum and found few posts regarding to ArcSDE driver, not sure if ArcSDE 10.2.2 is supported? And a number of links to download important .dll are leading to 404 errors....